# Is there an efficient way to check with an InputEventMouseButton wether the current position is colliding with an 2D Object?

Tags: godot

I would like to check with code like this:

```
func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT and event.pressed:
            spawnTower(event.position)
```

if there is something at the current mouse position, eg. enemies, other towers, terrain etc. and only if the point of interest has no collision, spawn a tower.
I did try to tackle this from the opposite site: have each collision shape signal when mouse enters/leaves the collision shape.
Wanting to add maybe up to 20 towers and potentially 100ish enemies this seems to be rather wasteful.
A hint for a better approach would be highly appreciated.
Kind regards, Jan Martin

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am sorry, maybe this is helpful for other or at least a future me.
So here is my solution:
First: add a RayCast2D, no code in script required, make sure to check "Collide With: Areas" in the Inspector.
Second: Add some code to main script like:

```
func checkForCollision(position: Vector2):
    get_node("RayCast2D").position = position
    get_node("RayCast2D").cast_to = Vector2(0,0) # sets the length of the ray to 0
    get_node("RayCast2D").force_raycast_update()
    print($RayCast2D.is_colliding())
    print($RayCast2D.get_collider ( ))
    return $RayCast2D.is_colliding()
```

this returns a boolean and prints some additional info.
To verify activate "Visible Collision Shapes" in the "Debug" drowdown.
Regards Martin